# Get SfB Online conferencing policy applied to user

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business

I'm trying to use an if statement to perform a check of conferencing policy applied to users via the LyncOnlineConnector PowerShell module.

```
Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity $Upn3 -Filter {ConferencingPolicy -eq "BposSAllModalityMinVideoBW"}
```

The above returns the user currently set in variable $Upn3 but this user currently has a conferencing policy of BposSAllModality. Not quite sure why it's returning the user object if it currently doesn't match the comparison operator but hoping someone can point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Comment: At a guess, I think `-Identity` and `-Filter` maybe aren't supposed to be used simultaneously (even though the cmdlet doesn't explicitly stop you). I think you maybe need to work the identity in to your filter via an `-and`.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I've tried the following but doesn't return anything nor does it error: Get-CsOnlineUser -Filter {(UserPrincipalName -eq $Upn3) -and (ConferencingPolicy -eq "BposSAllModality")}. I have however found a solution though and will explain in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following does what I want:

```
Get-CsOnlineUser $Upn3 | Select -ExpandProperty Conferencing*
```

I've set this as a variable and can call it as and when.